# How check if an email exist without send in Ruby? Use of email_veracity_checker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email-validation

I'm trying to create a ruby script that checks the real existence of some e-mail.
I've found `email_veracity_checker` but I don't understand how implement a simple test.
The "Readme" file only says the following:

```
# Add following entry in your config/environment.rb
config.gem 'email_veracity_checker', :lib => "email_check"
```

How to use:

```
#first param is user email address
#second sender address
#third param is domain address

#Note: It's not sending email, at the end point they quit connection.
EmailCheck.run("kiran@joshsoftware.com","no-reply@joshsoftware.com","joshsoftware.com").valid?
```

It's return can be true or false"

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? It looks pretty simple.
What it does is setting up an SMTP-connection, just like you do when you send a mail. At a certain point, in an SMTP-connection, your server says something like this:

> I'ld like to send a mail to ...@....com

Most of the servers will return an error when this address doesn't exist. After this, a normal SMTP-connection would be free to send the actual message body. This class, however, closes the connection at this point, so no mail will be sent.

However, before sending the quoted message, it needs to specify the sender's mail. So that's why you need to specify it. Besides that, you also need to define the owner's mail domain, because it's needed for the `EHLO` payload.

---

What about doing something like this (I'm using `mongo_mapper`, so this may be different in your situation):

```
class User
    include MongoMapper::document
    ...
    key mail, String, :required => true
    ...
    validate :validate_mail
    ...
    def validate_mail
        if !EmailCheck.run(self.mail, "no-reply@yourdomain.com", self.mail.split('@')[1]).valid?
            errors.add :mail, "is invalid."
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm very newbie in Ruby. And I want make the most simple way possible. If I want use your code I must include what more? Install gem or other requirement?

Comment: What ORM (Object Relation Mapper) are you using already? By default, this would be ActiveRecord (with PostgreSQL or SQLlite3).

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for a ruby script, you can do something like this. Just require the email check found on lib of that gem.

```
require 'email_check.rb'

is_valid = EmailCheck.run("kiran@joshsoftware.com", "no-reply@joshsoftware.com", "joshsoftware.com").valid?

puts "is valid: #{is_valid}"
```

Comment: This work with the test adresses `joshsoftware`but when I replace them by the adresses I would like to test, it sends me `false` instead of showing me all the opening connection... Do you have any idea ?